# How and when to use " Probably" when it's compared to " Maybe "

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Wat up?

I just really would like you guys, more particularly the Native Am.Eng Speakers to explain to me as clear and simple as possible how and when to use the words " Probably " vs " Maybe " in terms of comparing each other. 
I mean, on what those two words are or should be based on.

Answer (score 1):

These are "adverbials of probability".

Adverbs of probability are used to show how sure we are about a situation or event.

definitely, certainly, clearly and obviously show that something is very likely to happen (very high probability)

- We will definitely be there tomorrow.
- She is certainly coming to the party.
- It is clearly going to be wonderful weather tomorrow.
- They are obviously late.

possibly, perhaps, probably, maybe show that something may or may not happen:

- I’ll probably go out tonight - more likely than not
- I'll maybe go out tonight. - less certain

perhaps and possibly show that something is less likely to happen (low probability)